# Cannot resolve Hostname to IP, but IP to hostname works

Tags: networking, active-directory, resolve, domain-name-system

I have deployed a bunch of windows server VMs on a cloud hosting service. These machines are all joined to a domain controller on the same service, which also hosts DNS. All of the domain-joined machines have dynamic IP (along with the DC).

If I try to resolve any of the hostnames remotely, it fails. For example, I am in SQL Server Reporting Services and I need to connect to a remote server. I provide the hostname of the desired target server and this fails, but then if I provide the IP, this works. How can I pass the hostname and have this resolve to IP?

Is there anything I need to look for in the DNS server? It has records of the hostnames (in forward lookup I think), but reverse is empty. Isn't it the case that forward lookup resolves ip to hostname and reverse resolves hostname to ip? Also, I don't know what he subnet mask because this is not in my control, so the machines may not be in the same subnet - can this be a cause of the problem?

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are your examples from inside or outside? Have you verified DNS settings on each machine? From a host not resolving correctly have you run nslookup to see what reply you do or do not get from your DNS server? And you have it backwards, forward lookups resolve hostnames to IP addresses. Your questions are all over the place and seem to lack some basic foundations of networking. Keep it simple.

Comment: You're right, I do lack some basic foundations of networking. Even though I'm a developer, even I struggle with networking, bad I know. What do you mean by inside or outside? DNS settings have been verified, I will run nslookup.

Comment: When you create an Active Directory, it creates a new DNS namespace (zone if you will). Unless you ask THAT server, or a server it is replicating those zones to to resolve something you will not get an answer. Is is possible to replicate this zone to public DNS, but you need to figure out if you're doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd query the Nameserver directly with those host names with NSlookup to see what that gives you, if thats correct than check on the servers that that DNS server is the one that they need to ask for the IP.

> Is there anything I need to look for in the DNS server? It has records of the hostnames (in forward lookup I think), but reverse is empty. Isn't it the case that forward lookup resolves ip to hostname and reverse resolves hostname to ip? Also, I don't know what he subnet mask because this is not in my control, so the machines may not be in the same subnet - can this be a cause of the problem?

Forward resolves hostname to IP  Reverse does IP to name. I think thats your problem potentially.